# Is it possible to affect local variables from a callback function in C++?

Tags: c++, sqlite, callback

I'm tinkering with SQLite for an application I'm working on. As far as I can tell, the clearest documentation available describing how to get information out of a SQLite DB pertains to the use of sqlite3_exec() with a callback.

I intend to have a lot of different kinds of queries in my program, and different uses for the results, and it seems like I'm going to have to write callbacks for each one if I go that rout. What I'd much rather do is prepare a local variable with the necessary size and type to receive the query results, call the query and funnel the results into the local variable.

The way I see it, I have three options:

1. Pass my variable into the callback by reference
2. Have the callback access my local variable directly somehow
3. Spend a lot more time studying SQLite

So, here's what I want to know from you guys:

Are options 1 and 2 possible? If not, are there any really good general-case examples for how to query SQLite without sqlite3_exec and a callback that you can link me to?

Comment: Please post an [mcve]

Comment: @xaxxon minimal, complete, and verifiable example of what? Using sqlite3_exec with a callback is already covered by SQLite's website and I don't need help doing that; I'm not asking you guys to fix an existing problem with my code, and the only other thing I can see here that I might provide an example for are options 1 and 2, which are the things I'm not sure is possible and I'm asking you about.

Comment: @boxcartenant: You're right that it's covered by the documentation. And so the answer to your question is "yes", and it needs no question. But it looks like you're unfamiliar with C style callbacks, so, do note that one argument is supplied by the caller.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. But really, it's for asking about what the documentation covers, while claiming to not need help with that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What I claimed originally was that the documentation was unclear on operating without use of the callback, which as you've correctly pointed out, comes from the perspective of a person unfamiliar with c style callbacks. Brian's answer hit the nail on the head, as I wasn't asking for specific use-cases, but a general "is it possible to access a local variable from within the callback". His answer is evidence that the question is not too broad to provide a succinct answer. *So that's what the void argument is for*; simple.

Comment: And anyway, if my question evidences too much unfamiliarity with the subject matter to ask questions about it, then how in the world does this website operate? If I knew the answer, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: People on stackoverflow like code in all questions, even if the code doesn't work or makes no sense. You get used to it. I myself has a little trouble realizing what you meant by "local variable" without seeing any code, because I'd naturally be wanting to wrap the callback in some class and have some class member being altered (which could also be acheived through the void * param being an instance of the class.)

Comment: I think most people just use prepared statements and `sqlite3_step()` to get the results of queries instead of mucking with `sqlite3_exec()` callbacks. That function is mostly used for things where you don't care about the results, like creating tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All properly designed C-language APIs that accept callbacks allow you to pass a `void*` (or similar) argument to the API which will then be forwarded to your callback when it's called. You can use this argument to pass the address of your local variable. For example:

```
extern "C" int my_callback(void* dest /*, other args */) {
    auto* result = static_cast<MyResultType*>(dest);
    // modify *result appropriately
}

MyResultType result1;
sqlite3_exec(/* other args, */ query1, my_callback, &result1 /*, other args */);
// result of query1 is in result1
MyResultType result2;
sqlite3_exec(/* other args, */ query2, my_callback, &result2 /*, other args */);
// result of query2 is in result2
```